# unable to get response back in actionscript3 from servlet

Tags: actionscript-3, servlets

I am able to get data from as3 to servlet read it successfully but unable to send back to as3 from servlet.

Below is the AS3 code. The application is loaded on tomcat server.

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://localhost:8080/Demo/UserDataControllerServlet");

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

 loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

  add_txt.text ="http://localhost:8080/Demo/UserDataControllerServlet";

  var _vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

  _vars.emailId = "abc@gmail.com";
  _vars.phoneNumber = "9898989898";
  _vars.userAddress = "abc";
  _vars.userName = "abc";
  _vars.vendorAddress = "abc";
  _vars.vendorName = "abc";

  request.data = _vars;

  request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

  loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);

  loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
  loader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityError);
  loader.load(request);
  add_txt.text ="already sent........................";
  private function onSecurityError(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
  add_txt.text ="security error ........................";
  }
```

This should get execute after the response is back to as3.

```
private function handleComplete(event:Event):void {

add_txt.text ="in the response function";                
var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);             
trace("Message: " + loader.data);
add_txt.text = "========="+loader.data;             
}
private function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
add_txt.text = "Error loading URL.";
trace("Error loading URL.");
this.parent.removeChild(this);
}
```

Below is the servlet code: I am able to read data from request, but after out.write and out.close response is not going back to as3. I tried removing out.close() but even that didnt help.

```
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String emailId  = request.getParameter("emailId");       
        String phoneNumber = request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
        String userAddress = request.getParameter("userAddress");
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("Hello");
        out.close();
        }
```

Could you please help me out on this issue of not receiving data back in as3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should return a response in query string format to AS3, something just like this:

```
private function handleComplete(event:Event):void {

         add_txt.text ="in the response function";                 
         var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);             
         trace("Message: " + loader.data.success); // loading [success] value from response
         add_txt.text = "========="+loader.data.success;             
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String emailId  = request.getParameter("emailId");       
        String phoneNumber = request.getParameter("phoneNumber");
        String userAddress = request.getParameter("userAddress");
        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write("success=1");  // sending [success]
        out.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! sending response in query string format indeed worked..:)

Answer (score 0):

You're half way there. You need to treat the call to your servlet as a webservice call. Think of you AS as making an Ajax request to a servlet. Look up stuff on 'REST Servlets'. 
http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-hello-world-example/

Comment: I wouldnt need webservice calls here. This is simple urloader concept where 'as3' files are residing in same server. And as I said, I am able to read the data in servlet successfully sent from as3. I am facing problem in getting response back in as3 from servlet.

Comment: did you hit the servlet url in the browser? What do you get?

Comment: Yes. If I simply hit this url http://localhost:8080/Demo/UserDataControllerServlet in browser it returns me string written in doGet method